Product Filter Section in Ecommerce Website Project
I am working on an e-commerce website project. There is a filter system in this project, but there is no "filter" button. For filtering, you need to select the appropriate options and press one of the page buttons (First Page, 1, etc.). I share the code of the page with you. How can I create a filter button like this?
The important part
echo "<li><a href='shop.php?page=1"; if(!empty($aPath)){ echo "&".$aPath; }
but I couldn't do it
function getPaginator(){

/// getPaginator Function Code Starts ///

$per_page = 6;

global $db;

$aWhere = array();

$aPath = '';


/// Products Categories Code Starts ///

if(isset($_REQUEST['p_cat'])&&is_array($_REQUEST['p_cat'])){

foreach($_REQUEST['p_cat'] as $sKey=>$sVal){

if((int)$sVal!=0){

$aWhere[] = 'p_cat_id='.(int)$sVal;

$aPath .= 'p_cat[]='.(int)$sVal.'&';

}

}

}

/// Products Categories Code Ends ///

/// Categories Code Starts ///

if(isset($_REQUEST['cat'])&&is_array($_REQUEST['cat'])){

foreach($_REQUEST['cat'] as $sKey=>$sVal){

if((int)$sVal!=0){

$aWhere[] = 'cat_id='.(int)$sVal;

$aPath .= 'cat[]='.(int)$sVal.'&';

}

}

}

/// Categories Code Ends ///

$sWhere = (count($aWhere)>0?' WHERE '.implode(' or ',$aWhere):'');

$query = "select * from products ".$sWhere;

$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);

$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);

echo "<li><a href='shop.php?page=1";

if(!empty($aPath)){ echo "&".$aPath; }

echo "' >".'First Page'."</a></li>";

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++){

echo "<li><a href='shop.php?page=".$i.(!empty($aPath)?'&'.$aPath:'')."' >".$i."</a></li>";

};

echo "<li><a href='shop.php?page=$total_pages";

if(!empty($aPath)){ echo "&".$aPath; }

echo "' >".'Last Page'."</a></li>";

/// getPaginator Function Code Ends ///



To add a filter button that allows users to apply filters before
navigating to a page, you can create a separate form element
containing your filter options and a submit button. Here's how you can
Modify your code to include a filter button:

<form method="get" action="shop.php">
    <!-- select option for product categories -->
    <select name="cat[]" multiple>
        <option value="1">Category 1</option>
        <option value="2">Category 2</option>
    </select>
    <!-- submit button -->
    <button type="submit">Filter</button>
</form>


Then, you can adjust the logic in your PHP code to handle the
submitted filter options. Modify the $aPath variable accordingly.
Here's how you can do it:

$aPath = '';

// Check if filter options are submitted
if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_array($_GET['cat'])) {
    foreach($_GET['cat'] as $sKey => $sVal) {
        if((int)$sVal != 0) {
            $aWhere[] = 'cat_id=' . (int)$sVal;
            $aPath .= 'cat[]=' . (int)$sVal . '&';
        }
    }
}


Now, when users select filter options and click the "Filter" button,
the form will submit the selected options to the shop.php page. The
PHP code will then handle these filter options and generate the
appropriate URL for pagination.

